# Why does my bidirectional port only give my output but 8'hxx for input?

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to use a inout port for the dataBus of RAM. I have designed the RAM with a distinct input port for dataBUs_in and output dataBus_out. Later linked them to a bidirection port in the top module. After simulating the inout port only gives the output datBus_out and for dataBus_in it displays a 8'hxx.
Also I have tried using two always blocks in my RAM design, each for write and read.

topmodule code:

```
ram_cpu ram_cpu_top(
    .clock(top_clock),
    .write(top_write),
    .writeBar(top_writeBar),
    .ramEnable(top_ramEnable),
    .dataBus_in(top_dataBus_in),
    .addressBus(top_addressBus),
    .dataBus_out(top_dataBus_out)
    );
    assign dataBus = (internal_control == 1'b0) ? top_dataBus_in : 8'hzz;
    assign top_dataBus_out = dataBus;
```

ram design:

```
always @ (posedge clock)
begin //write
    if(ramEnable) begin
        if(write == 1'b1) begin
            
            ram[addressBus] <= dataBus_in;
        end 
  
        
    else if(write == 1'b0) begin
            dataBus_out <= ram[addressBus];     
             
        end 
        
    end 
end
```

Comment: In order to debug a bidirectional port (`inout`), you need to show the drivers in both directions

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I'm using the inout port for the first time. I don't quite understand how this can be done. I have tried to write this part seeing the IO buffer logic, but I really didn't understand how to drive a signal when my buffer is set to high impedance. Could you please elaborate? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`dataBus` is the common, bidirectional net. `top_dataBus_in` should be driven by `dataBus`. `dataBus` should be conditionally driven by `top_dataBus_out`

```
assign top_dataBus_in = dataBus;
assign dataBus = (internal_control == 1'b0) ? top_dataBus_out : 8'hzz;
```

Note: when `internal_control` is 1, some other logic should be driving `dataBus` or it will be floating. Floating is only okay if noting needs to sense the value. In most bidirectional designs a pull-down or pull-up is connected to the bus.